# Need to create field from square cells on picturebox

Tags: c#

I want to draw squares on picturebox, for this I use this code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        Point point = new Point(0, 0);
        SolidBrush pen = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        Size size = new Size(10, 10);
        if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x) && int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out y))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Map.CreateGraphics())
            {
                int n = x * y;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    Rectangle[] rects = 
                    {
                        new Rectangle(point, size) 
                    };
                    point = point + size;

                    g.FillRectangles(pen, rects);
                }
            }

        }
```

The main issue that for this aim i have to make something like this: point = point.X + size.Width, but they are different types.

Comment: Did you resolve your problems?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many issues and you really need to learn about drawing in Winforms.

But the actual question is a simple one:

You can add a `Size` to a `Point` like this:

```
point = Point.Add(point, size);
```

This make use of one of the many, rather unknown methods in the `Point` class.

Note: The `Size` and `Rectangle` classes also hold useful methods!

---

You loop makes no sense, I'm afraid. You should create a `List<Rectangle> rectangles = new List<Rectangle>` **outside** and add to it **inside** the loop. After it you can  call `FillRectangles(Brushes.somecolor, rectangles.ToaArray()) )`..!

As for the other issues: You will soon find out why your graphics won't persist etc..

Hint: Winforms graphics basic rule #1 :

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..